# Implementing login/logout in php or Java servlets?

Tags: java, php, servlets, authentication, logout

I want to create a website where someone can login and logout, upload and store files. it just for a college project, i have experience in both php and java, what would be the best way to implement this functionality into a website using either java or php.

Would there be a frameworks that provided login/logout functionality out of the box instead of me writing the code for it so i can focus on the upload and download of files?

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If it is a college project I recommend you to write your own code without using any frameworks. If you are doing it in java, login is really simple. You just have to create a jsp page with a html form in it. Access the login credentials inside the servlet doPost method and authenticate.
- There are some external api s which can be used if you need more security and ease authentication and authorization. [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) is one such open source project. But I highly recommend you to use your own code if you are not very sound in client-server programming.

Answer (score 0):

since this is a college project, there is no need to find some framework to finish login/logout, in Java Servlet, just use session to finish that.

It had better for you using MVC.

For upload you can use the apache upload framework.

But for the enterprise projects, most of them are using "ssh".

Answer (score 0):

For Java you could look at Spring Security http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/